# I have a C# solution where the same file belongs to multiple projects. How?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

There is a file `C:\Users\Me\source\repos\MyProject\VersionInfo.cs` that is somehow contained within all but one projects in the `MyProject` solution; editing one copy of it simultaneously edits all of them, but it only shows up once in source control, at the solution level. How is this possible? How can I add it to the last project? I tried "add existing file" but that just copied it into that folder... if it helps any there is a little blue "arrow in a box" icon on it...

[image]

Comment: You need "Add as Link" to prevent the copy.  Click the arrow on the Add button to get it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a file which was added as a link. You can read about it for example [here](https://andrewlock.net/including-linked-files-from-outside-the-project-directory-in-asp-net-core/#adding-files-from-outside-the-project-by-linking) or [here](https://jeremybytes.blogspot.com/2019/07/linking-files-in-visual-studio.html). You can achieve this via *Add* -> *Existing Item* dialog but instead of clicking "Add" click on the dropdown arrow to the right and select "Add As Link":

[image]

Or by manually editing .csproj:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="..\OtherFolder\VersionInfo.cs" Link="VersionInfo.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! I had no idea Visual Studio had that feature.