# CrossProject global using in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I am refactoring some of my code now that C#10 is in place. I noticed that the amount of references is insane.
For that reason, I thought to refactor everything that is shared across every single project into one "shared one" using `global usings`, but it is not working as expected.

Just for the "minimal" example.

I have one class library that configures API configuration (middlewares and so on). Then I have other few libraries.

The key here is that I would like to have one single library called "setup" which references all the other libraries and, using "global usings", be able to import that library in the webapplications that contains all the domain logic

But, when I create a file in the new `setup` project with `global using Shared.API.xxx` seems not to do anything.

I also imported in the webapplication the `setup` project doing the next:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="Shared.Setup" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Is this possible to do crossproject global usings?

Note: When I import `global using Shared.API.xxx` anywhere inside the webapplication works as expected.

Comment: So the idea is to have global using defined in one project and used in all other ones?

Comment: @GuruStron yes, exactly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#global-modifier) state - `global using`s are constrained to the files in compilation (project):

> Adding the global modifier to a using directive means that using is applied to all files in the compilation (typically a project).

And imagine imports pollution if you could introduce transitive global usings.

But you can share `global using` for example by adding them manually [as a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61577475/i-have-a-c-sharp-solution-where-the-same-file-belongs-to-multiple-projects-how/61577624#61577624) to every project:

- In VS - *right click on target project* -> *Add* -> *Existing Item* but instead of clicking "Add" click on the dropdown arrow to the right and select "Add As Link"
- Or manually editing the .csproj by adding next:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Relative_Path_To_Shared.Setup.SharedUsingsFile.cs" Link="SharedUsingsFile.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```